# React Native keep scrollview position with useSelector

Tags: react-native, redux, scrollview

I have a situation like this I use scrollview and I use scrollTo when it first opened to screen but when i do this my useSelector re render the scrollview and going to the beginning and scrolling again how can I keep scroll view position with useSelector

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState(useSelector(reduxData => reduxData.data1));
const [data2, setData2] = useState(useSelector(reduxData => reduxData.data2));
```

when I changed this state like this

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState([]);
const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
```

scrollTo work perfectly, how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the state using useSelector inside useState. What if you define a variable from redux like this:

```
let data1 = useSelector(reduxData => reduxData.data1);
```

And then use useEffect to scroll like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  scrollTo(data1)
},[data1]);
// OR IF data1 DOES NOT CONTAIN THE PLACE TO SCROLL SUBSTITUTE 
// THE VARIABLE AS useEffect WILL ONLY RUN WHEN SUCH VARIABLE 
// CHANGES
```

Does it work?